# what is the difference between string a="hello" and string a=(char *)"hello" in c++?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between these two string initializations in c++?
i get the same output in both the programs.
Program 1

```
void main(){
    string a = "hello";
    cout<<a;
}
```

program 2

```
void main(){
    string a = (char *)"hello";
    cout<<a;
}
```

Comment: You could try to debug it, since std::string is a template class you can step into it and see which constructors and methods are called. Spoiler alert: There should be no difference.

Answer (score 5):

`"hello"` is a [string literal](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal). Its type is

> `const char[N]`, where `N` is the size of the string [...] including the null terminator.

So in this case, the type is `const char[6]`. Note the `const`.

Now [`std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) can be constructed (constructor 5 in the link) from a `const char*`. Again, note the `const`.

In C++, you can pass a non-`const` object into a function that expects a `const`. In your case, your cast `(char *)` removes the `const`, but then immediately puts the `const` back on in the constructor call.

So basically, no difference. They will compile to exactly the same thing.

---

A few additional notes:

1. casting away `const`-ness is very dangerous. If you had actually tried to change anything in the `char` array, your program would have had [**Undefined Behaviour**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).
2. `using namespace std;` is [widely considered to be bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/1171191).
3. `void main()` is **not** a valid signature for the `main` function; [it must return an `int`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function).
4. Using `C`-style casts in `C++` can also be considered a bad practice - it is harder to spot in code, and `C++` provides safer equivalents for more specific situations: [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast), [`static_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_cast), [`dynamic_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dynamic_cast), and (the most dangerous) [`reinterpret_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reinterpret_cast).

Comment: thanks for the answer, can you provide 1 example for additional notes 1 casting away......

Answer (score 4):

Nothing actually, that additional `char *` type casting is not needed.

In both the cases copy initialization is done.

```
string (const char* s);
```

[read more on copy initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization)

Answer (score 0):

`std::string` is a typedef for a specialization of [`basic_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string) class templated on a `char` (objects that represent sequences of characters).

The expression `string a = "hello"` corresponds to a stream of characters whose size is allocated statically.

Short, simple and typesafe `std::cout` is a typedef of [`ostream`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ostream/ostream/) class templated on standard objects (provides support for high-level output operations).

`cout` means "the standard character output device", and the verb `<<` means "output the object".

`cout << a;` sends the string like a stream to the `stdout`.

`char *` are special pointers to a constant character, they point to ASCII strings e.g.:

```
const char * s = "hello world";
```

The expression `(char *)"hello"` corresponds to a `char *` pointer, where you are casting away `const`, but then the constructor immediately puts the `const` back on the call.

`cout`, therefore, will print a string because it has a special operator for `char *` wich it will treat as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string that outputs strings.

`char*` or `const char*`, `cout` will treat the operand as a pointer to (the first character of) a C-style string, and prints the contents of that string: